# Как задать ключу в объекте значение ключа из другого объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

У меня есть объект с 2 объектами внутри. Нужно чтобы ключ address имел бы своим значением значения ключей lat и lng из второго объекта. Как можно это сделать? Ниже пример где я пробовал через location.lat.

```
const randomFloat = function(min, max, numberDecimals) {
    let result = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    result = parseFloat(result.toFixed(numberDecimals));
    return result;
};

let arr = {

    place: {
        country: 'China',
        city: 'Peking',
        address: location.lat
    },

    location: {
        lat: randomFloat(35.65000, 35.70000, 5),
        lng: randomFloat(139.70000, 139.80000, 5)
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ниче не понял..

Comment: @entithat спасибо, опечатка

Comment: `arr.place.address = arr.location`

Comment: @entithat Как передать в ключ address значения двух ключей из объекта location?

Comment: @Rumata, так? ```arr.place.address = {lat: arr.location.lat, lng: arr.location.lng};```

Comment: @entithat Да, спасибо, если добавите как ответ смогу принять!

Comment: @OliverPatterson Спасибо, да, только мне нужно не вручную ввести значение а сделать чтобы он автоматически подцеплял его из location, решение в предыдущем комменте помогло

Comment: @Rumata, та ладно, пожалуйста